# boolean[] in conditional types expands to true[] | false[]

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

This conditional type tries to make the type argument `U` into an array:

```js
type MakeArray<U> = U extends boolean ? Array<U> : U;
```

However, when passed `boolean`:

```js
type T5 = MakeArray<boolean>;
```

The result is `type T5 = true[] | false[]`.

I've seen https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30029 but that seems to deal with promises/return values and was in theory fixed in TS 3.5.

I.e. AFAICT that issue is about primitives and distributing over unions, but I'm explicitly checking against `extends boolean` and not something like `extends boolean | number | string`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is probably a bit late but it works by infering the type argument if an array like this

```
type MakeArray<T, V = T> = T extends Array<infer V> ? T : Array<V>;

type TBoolean = MakeArray<boolean>; // boolean[]
type TBooleanArray = MakeArray<Array<boolean>>; // boolean[]

type TString = MakeArray<string>; // string[]
type TStringArray = MakeArray<Array<string>>; // string[]
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to be "Distributive Conditional Types". See
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types.

This allows you to control how generic union parameters are expanded:

```
type MakeArray<U> = [U] extends [boolean] ? Array<U> : U;
type T5 = MakeArray<boolean>;
```

This gives you `type T5 = boolean[]` as you expect.